# javascript array error splice map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary, splice

could you please help me understand the error in the following code, i am trying to run it in jsfiddle and says that there is an unexpected } right before the first call to console.log:

```
function deleteItem(type,id){
   var ids,index;
   ids = data.allItems[type].map(function(current){
     return current.id;

});
index = ids.indexOf(id);
data.allItems[type].splice(index,1);


}
var data = {
     allItems:{
         exp:[{id:2,desc:'pants',value:200},{id:5,desc:'jacket',value:1200}, 
              {id:7,desc:'holiday',value:5800}],
         inc:[{id:7,desc:'salary',value:3000},{id:9,desc:'project',value:5000}]
          },
     total: {exp:9200,inc:11,000};
};

console.log(data);
deleteItem('exp',5);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `data.allItems[type] = data.allItems[type].filter(current => current.id !== id);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got redundant semicolon in this line:

```
     total: {exp:9200,inc:11,000};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line where you define `total` key in the `data` variable it should be `11000` not `11,000`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error, try removing the `;` from the end of `total: {exp:9200,inc:11,000};`